# HTTPS redirect Elastic Beanstalk Environment Puma Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I am unable to redirect http://example.com to https://example.com.  I tried various configurations but nothin works.

Based on the research, I have realized that I need to add this to nginx config.

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
          rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
```

I create a new config file in the ..ebextensions directory with the following content,

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
}

log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                '$http_x_forwarded_for';

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;
    set $hour $4;
  }

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /assets {
    alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /public {
    alias /var/app/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

save it and do

1. eb deploy
2. Goto http://example.com

I still get the "unsure" message.

I also used the content as is from [this](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/ruby-puma/https-redirect-ruby-puma.config).  But that does not work either.

What am i missing?

Sunil

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code do I see a listen to 443 which is the HTTPS.

This is my SSL script.

```
upstream puma_production {
  server unix:/home/deploy/games.directory/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name games.directory;
  root /home/deploy/games.directory/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_production;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate '';
  ssl_certificate_key '';
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ''
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  # OCSP Stapling ---
  # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/games.directory/chain.pem;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  location @puma_production {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://puma_production;

    access_log /home/deploy/games.directory/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/deploy/games.directory/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
     gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }
}
```

Comment: I configured HTTPS on 443 via the EB web console.

Answer (score 0):

Use EB file keys to customise for nginx conf generation template.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Create a file .ebextensions/01_puma_nginx.conf (Configuration files are executed in alphabetical order, so tweak name prefix based on additional requirements) with following content.

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
Paste your custom nginx configuration template content here....
```

Instead of building your own template and break things, check the existing template in the current instance and tweak only required things (here just your http redirection part).

Well, if this seems a little complicated, you can use rails force_ssl option by checking 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header

```
  force_ssl if: :ssl_required?

  def ssl_required?
    if request.headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"]!="https"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Comment: You could also use force_ssl within rails by checking header 'X-Forwarded-Proto'

Comment: @vlad, Not sure if listening to port 443 is necessary as usually elasticbeanstalk is be coupled with load balancer which handles ssl and routes requests to instances with an additional X-Forwarded-Proto header. (Not enough rep to comment on your answer :P)

Comment: I did force_ssl option and it worked.  I got enough direction on the ebextention option to try that too.  Thanks.  I will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS is a very common problem needing to be solved. So AWS have documented the solution here, which covers all their different Elastic Beanstalk platforms:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html